# swift avfoundation AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate capture method

Tags: swift, image-processing, computer-vision, avfoundation

Hello I am relatively new to swift and the avfoundation framework.  I am currently trying to implement a custom toy camera app that uses image processing.  My problem is that I am trying to process each frame or each X frames automatically using my image processing algorithm then apply a layer to the preview, and also allow the user to capture the preview image plus using an IBAction ui button that outputs that image to the screen.  The image processing step would capture lower res images that do not get outputted to the screen, while the ibaction capture should capture a standard jpeg and output it to the screen.

My question is what is the best way to implement something like this?

I have noticed that the logic would probably go into the AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate method `capture(_ captureOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput, ...)` but there would also be two different AVCapturePhotoOutput() objects calling `capturePhoto(with: photoSettings, delegate: self)` that calls the `capture(_ captureOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput, ...)`, from what I understand.  Would I check in the `capture(_ captureOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput, ...)` method which captureOutput object was sent from the capturePhoto(with: photoSettings, delegate: self) method called by the different AVCapturePhotoOutput() objects?

where the full method signature of `capture(_ captureOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput, ...)` is

```
capture(_ captureOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput,
                 didFinishProcessingPhotoSampleBuffer photoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?,previewPhotoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?,
                 resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings,
                 bracketSettings: AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings?,
                 error: Error?)
```

Or would these two different capture functions be done on two different threads?

To further elaborate, I have two working camera apps which two different functionality.  One with the image processing and layer implementation and another with preview capture and output to UI view.  The respective AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate capture methods are as follows:

image processing camera:

```
  public func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput,
                      didFinishProcessingPhotoSampleBuffer photoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?,
                      previewPhotoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?,
                      resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings,
                      bracketSettings: AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings?,
                      error: Error?) {

    var imageTexture: MTLTexture?
    var previewImage: UIImage?
    if error == nil {
      imageTexture = convertToMTLTexture(sampleBuffer: photoSampleBuffer)
      previewImage = convertToUIImage(sampleBuffer: previewPhotoSampleBuffer)
    }
    delegate?.videoCapture(self, didCapturePhotoTexture: imageTexture, previewImage: previewImage)
  }
```

capture image to UI camera:

```
func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput,
             didFinishProcessingPhotoSampleBuffer photoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?,previewPhotoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?,
             resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings,
             bracketSettings: AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings?,
             error: Error?) {

    if let error = error {
        print("Error capturing photo: \(error)")
    } else {
        if let sampleBuffer = photoSampleBuffer,
           let previewBuffer = previewPhotoSampleBuffer,
        let dataImage = AVCapturePhotoOutput.jpegPhotoDataRepresentation(forJPEGSampleBuffer: sampleBuffer, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: previewBuffer) {

            if let image = UIImage(data: dataImage) {
                self.capturedImage.image = image
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Where capturedImage is `@IBOutlet weak var capturedImage: UIImageView!` and the convert methods are functions within a custom class. How would I go about getting the functionality of both of those capture(...) methods into one app?

Comment: It's better to finish the method's name ` capture(_ captureOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput, ...) `,     Is it   func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhotoSampleBuffer photoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings, bracketSettings: AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings?, error: Error?)

Comment: Correct.  That is the full method's name.

Answer (score 0):

I think the apple's document [AVCapturePhotoOutput](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephotooutput) is clear. You should take a look.

I don't know two different capture functions are done on two different threads or not. Since the AVFoundation Kit is not open source as I know.

I don't think it matters.

As apple's document, you register the delegate by `capturePhoto(with:delegate:)` , and get the picture by the callback that apple implemented by default `photoOutput(_:didFinishProcessingPhoto:error:)`

By the way , the method `photoOutput(_:didFinishProcessingPhoto:previewPhoto:resolvedSettings:bracketSettings:error:)`   is deprecated. you could check [this page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephotocapturedelegate/1778647-photooutput)

Comment: So each delegate can have its own capture(...) method?

Comment: Yes. Each delegate will monitor the capture progress ——  willBegin 、willCapture、didCapture、didFinish .     And  so sorry . Just now I mistook the response as another question.

Comment: @stochasticcrap, any problems you met ?